# Drupal DB Error when Inserting data into table : Escaped Quotes?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-6

I am having a particularly tough issue i have to solve but have yet to crack the nut. 
I have posted about this in the drupal issue queue but i might just be getting ignored. Here is the link to [Drupal Issue 1061458](http://drupal.org/node/1061458).

This is done in Drupal 6 on my centos box using apache mysql and php.

I am trying to do an insert every time someone arrives at a page so i put a silly blank page out there with create content then i put my dynamic block up there to run my code from the module. I make the block call a function that grabs the user's ip address and stores it with a flag in the db until that person registers.

Here is the generated error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near &#039;group) VALUES (&#039;&#039;,&#039;&#039;)&#039; at line 1 query: INSERT INTO group_landing_connection (ipaddress,group) VALUES (&#039;&#039;,&#039;&#039;) in /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/MODULE/MODULE.module on line 1130.
```

With those exact escaped quotes then here is the offending code in the block function

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO {group_landing_connection} (ipaddress,group) VALUES ('%s','%d')";
db_query($sql,$ip,$group);
```

Where Ip and group are set up above. And here is the db formatting from the module install file

```
  $schema['group_landing_connection'] = array(
'fields' => array(
  'dbid' => array('type' => 'serial', 'unsigned' => TRUE, 'not null' => TRUE, ),
  'ipaddress' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => '30', 'not null' => TRUE, ),
  'group' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => '10', 'not null' => TRUE, ),
),
'primary key' => array('dbid'),
```

);

I tried many things from setting the dbid to null and make the auto increment value. To running cron and flushing the cache. Block cache is turned off. I even tried using the %b for binary data input but nope. I tried removing the replacement values and hard coding numbers and not luck. I tried doing this call right after a db call that works and it still failed so I don't think it is the block's fault. I even tried doing the safer db_write_record call with this code

```
$data = array(
  'ipaddress' => '3',
  'group' => '3',
);
drupal_write_record('np_group_landing_connection', $data);
```

But no luck either anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group is a reserved word, rename your column
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Or you can say group_landing_connection.group 
"Exception: A word that follows a period in a qualified name must be an identifier, so it need not be quoted even if it is reserved"

But I would just rename it anyway

Comment: You are a god! This was exactly the problem. I did not even know that mysql had reserved words why don't they teach this!!! Well any way thank you so much.

Comment: All words that could have a special meaning in SQL are reserved (and then some more). And group is because of `GROUP BY`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html for a full list.